# AWS deployment group creation fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create a deployment group for an ECS service that I have already created but on entering all the values and clicking `create deployment group` i receive the alert:

```
Deployment group's ECS service must be configured for the external controller.
```

I am unable to understand as to what must I change in my ECS Service config to rectify the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have created your ECS Service resource via Cloud Formation or did not configure it correctly in the AWS Console ECS Service creation. As for Cloud Formation, this is still not supported as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codedeploy-deploymentgroup.html#cfn-codedeploy-deploymentgroup-deploymentstyle) as of this writing. Here are at least two ways on how you can proceed without getting the error.

1. In the AWS Console, during ECS Service creation, specify ***"Blue/green deployment"*** as **Deployment type** under **Deployments section**. This in turn will also create your deployment group for you automatically after service creation.

   [image]
2. Using `aws-cli`, add this property and value to your JSON file when calling the `aws ecs create-service` command.

   ```
   {
     ...
     "deploymentController": {
       "type": "CODE_DEPLOY"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```